# Multi column distinct count in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

Is there any workaround to do a multi column distinct count in JPQL?

It appears that JPQL supports only single expression counts in queries and since subqueries can't be used in from part is is not possible to express it like this

```
select count(*) from (select distinct a, b, c from Entity e)
```

Comment: what would be the expected outcome - count(a) + count(b) + count(c)?

Comment: @kostja It's more relevant if the distinct flag is added to count, I updated my question